# Connect HTML with Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, html, quick-links

Is it possible to add an Html page as a web part inside SharePoint.

I want this html page to have rows of links that once clicked, it would bring users to specific folder inside a Document Library on SharePoint.

Comment: You can use Quick Links web part also....Are you using modern experience or classic experience??

Comment: We are using classic Expereince. Is that problem when it comes to using Quick Links ?  can you elaborate on how to use quick links, also preferably having in mind that I want a background picture.

Comment: If you are using classic exp then you can use content editor web part also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

If you are using Classic experience then you can use **Content Editor** web part to add HTML file to SharePoint Page.

You can enable adding scripts(content editor web part) from Office 365 Admin Portal.

**Reference**:

1. [Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc).
2. [Content Editor Web Part missing in Office 365 Dev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/content-editor-web-part-missing-in-office-365-dev).

You can add hyperlinks inside your html code like given below:

```
<a href="siteUrl/DocumentLibrary/Folder1" target="_blank"> Folder1 </a>
```

**Solution 2**:

You can also use **Promoted Links** list in SharePoint.

**Reference**:

1. [How and Why to Use Promoted Links in SharePoint](https://lydonsolutions.com/2019/02/05/promoted-links-in-sharepoint/).
2. [How to add SharePoint Tiles, promoted links, to your site](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-add-sharepoint-tiles-promoted-links-to-your-site/).
3. [Promoted Links App](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Promoted-Links.htm).

Comment: thank you. Can the html page have hyperlinks to specific folder inside a Document Library ?

Comment: Yes, you can create hyperlinks using anchor tags in your html and pass the correct url of your folder. See updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: I will let you know when I try it and mark it as answered if it really helps. thank u

Comment: Sure, let me know if you found any error or you need any help.