# Alternate CSS Does Not Set on Sub-Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, inheritance, style

I am using Office 365 and having a horrible time setting CSS for sub-sites.

I have set my **Alternate CSS** set at https://site.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx but even though it is set to work for all sites it is only working for the top-level site.

[image]

I would like this CSS file to be inherited by all of the sub-sites.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Have you set this option on all sub-sites or just Parent site?

Comment: Thank You @GaneshSanap, I thought this would push it down. It works on all the pages other than Web Part pages. The Web Part pages do not take any CSS and the old trick of adding CSS as a web part is not working because the is no HTML web part any longer.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks, Josh

Comment: Settings this option in all sub-sites is working except web part pages, right? For web part pages I guess you can add Content Editor or Script Editor web part to set the CSS.

Comment: I do not have either of those Web Parts available.  It is a new format of Web Part page I have not seen before.  I cannot share a screenshot in this box but it is a sub-set of the "normal" Web Parts.

Comment: In SharePoint online, in order to add the Content Editor web part, you need to enable Custom Script feature from admin center, [Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/content-editor-web-part-missing-in-office-365-dev).

Comment: It is turned on and his been turned on for more than 24 hours. I think I am going to try and rebuild the page to make it look like the Web Parts page in the Screenshot in the top of the reference page you sent me because that is what I am used to working with.

Comment: try alternative solutions given in reference to Enable content editor web part. Also Check References in my Answer.

Comment: @GaneshSanap it also looks like https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/subsite/_layouts/15/settings.aspx is not a valid URL so I am not sure I am setting the CSS for everything.

Comment: This is settings page of your SharePoint site. Are you not able to access the site settings?

Comment: I have added the CSS for all pages and it is running on most pages but not on all custom pages.

Comment: Then custom css on the custom pages maybe overriding this CSS. Try inspecting elements and it's classes using Developer tools of browser

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working as you are setting then you can set the Alternate CSS URL option on all your Sub-sites specifying the URL of CSS file you want to apply.

**Enable Content Editor in SharePoint Online**:

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint admin center using URL : https://DOMAIN-admin.sharepoint.com/
2. Go to Tenant Settings using URL:  https://DOMAIN-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx
3. Scroll down to `Custom Script > Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites`
4. It takes about 24 hours for the change to take effect.
5. Replace `DOMAIN` in URL with your domain, before clicking on link.

**Reference**:

1. [Content Editor Web Part missing in Office 365 Dev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121115/content-editor-web-part-missing-in-office-365-dev).
2. [Missing web part and features in office 365](https://mstechtalk.com/missing-web-part-features-office-365/).
3. [Allow or prevent custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fTurn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f).

Answer (score 0):

Since these pages were set up as New/Modern (Post 2016) pages this technique does not work for those pages.